# Attempted to set ReadOverrideEffectiveIdentity for Service Principal but received forbidden response

Tags: c#, azure, powerbi, azure-active-directory, powerbi-embedded

I am working through trying to create an embed token for an SSAS Live Connection report in power bi.  As part of my troubleshooting I came across articles stating [to setup the ReadOverrideEffectiveIdentity](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Developer/PBE-with-Service-Principal-Creating-embed-token-for-accessing/td-p/2083931) for the Service Principal.

In doing so I followed [these steps](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Developer/Can-t-grant-ReadOverrideEffectiveIdentity-as-a-Service-Principal/m-p/2920703) to verify that the service principal has the permissions required.

However, when I run the below code I get a Forbidden response back.

I ran the below code to obtain the results I want.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            using var client = new HttpClient();
            var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "identifier", "APPLICATION ID" },
                { "datasourceAccessRight", "ReadOverrideEffectiveIdentity" }
            };
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
            var response = await client.PostAsync("https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/gateways/GATEWAYID/datasources/DATASET/users", content);
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(responseString);
        }
    }
}
```

I also attempted to use the following and got forbidden as well:

```
POST  https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/gateways/GATEWAYID/datasources/DATASETID/users

Request Body JSON 
{ 
    "identifier": "APPLICATION ID", 
    "datasourceAccessRight": "ReadOverrideEffectiveIdentity" 
}
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you've authenticated those REST API calls.  You would need and Authorization header with a Access Token for the Gateway Admin?  You might find it simpler to user the Power BI .NET Client: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerBI.Api/

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I have used the Power BI .Net Client to edit TOM but haven't seen or come across where I would use it for creating embed tokens.  How would I authenticate the above code?

Answer (score 0):

To authenticate this call get an Access Token for Power BI

```
async Task<string> GetAccessTokenForPBI(string clientId, string clientSecret, string tenantId)
{

    string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default" };

    // Create a confidential client to authorize the app with the AAD app
    IConfidentialClientApplication clientApp = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                                                                    .Create(clientId)
                                                                    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                                                                    .WithAuthority(new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/token"))
                                                                    .Build();
    // Make a client call if Access token is not available in cache
    var authenticationResult = await clientApp.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
    return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
}
```

And use that token in a Bearer Auth header on your web request.